# how to allow fullscreen model with in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i am creating a iframe using this js:

**parent.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "demo.html");
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "retNotif;");
ifrm.style.width = "540px";
ifrm.style.height = "200px";
ifrm.style.minHeight = "100px";
ifrm.style.position = "fixed";
ifrm.style.bottom = "150px";
ifrm.style.left = "0px";
ifrm.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
ifrm.style.zIndex = "9999";
ifrm.frameBorder = "0";
ifrm.allowTransparency = "true";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
```

**in iframe (demo.html)** : i have a normal bootstrap model

i want to show model inside the iframe fullscreen how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "demo.html");
    ifrm.setAttribute("id", "retNotif;");
    ifrm.style.width = "100vw";
    ifrm.style.height = "100vh";
    ifrm.style.minHeight = "100px";
    ifrm.style.position = "fixed";
    ifrm.style.top = "0";
    ifrm.style.left = "0";
    ifrm.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    ifrm.style.zIndex = "9999";
    ifrm.frameBorder = "0";
    ifrm.allowTransparency = "true";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
  }
</script>
```

A fixed iframe on the top left with a 100% width and height.